# focus() doesn't work with anchor link

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

```
<a id="news_click" href="#news"> <span style="color:#B2B2B2" class="radius secondary label">Do you want fresh news and feeds?</span></a>

<div class="large-5 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <form id="email_form" data-validate="parsley" data-trigger="focusin focusout">
                </br>
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="hg" name="email" data-notblank="true" data-type="email">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom_blue" id="news"></div>
```

---

```
$('#news_click').click(function () {
    $('form#email_form input#email.hg').focus();
});
```

The focus event only works if i remove the `<div class="bottom_blue" id="news"></div`. This is not an option since this is an anchor link.

Any idea? Probably the problem is that js is executed before the anchor.

**EDIT:** Apparently this works in chrome, not in FF.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tchd5/)

Comment: Side note, this `$('form#email_form input#email.hg')` should be `$('#email')`. And your fiddle works for me.

Comment: @j08691 not in firefox

Comment: Yup, just saw that. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you need to account for the click event and focus as a race condition in Firefox. Use either:

```
$('#news_click').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#email').focus();
});
```

or

```
$('#news_click').click(function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){$('#email').focus();},10);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tchd5/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an angle bracket at the end of `<div class="bottom_blue" id="news"></div`...

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jBd77/)

Use this instead:

```
<div class="bottom_blue" id="news"></div>
```

Also, try changing this:

```
$('form#email_form input#email.hg').focus();
```

To this:

```
$('#email').focus();
```

There can only be one element with the same `id` anyway, so it makes no difference how specific you are.

**EDIT:** Firefox seems to visit the `href` after the `email` box is focused... You can either use `preventDefault()` as in j08691's answer, or take the `href` attribute off the link (see the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBd77/2/)).

Comment: Just added the demo, hope you wont mind! +1 but i reckon real issue must be somewhere else `:)`