# Firefox: Anchor and Focus Input Field based on Starting URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are similar threads here discussing the fact that Firefox doesn't focus anchored elements properly, and they suggest some kind of timeout-focus etc.
[focus() doesn't work with anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577797/focus-doesnt-work-with-anchor-link)

I start from a Page URL e.g.
http://myapp.com/page#elementID

Firefox anchors `elementID` on page load correctly (scrolls into view), but it doesn't auto-focus `elementID`. I need to also focus the field.

When I add this in my jQuery Document.Ready,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Handle the possible #-Anchor 
    // Firefox does not focus the anchored element (Chrome does).
    // Firefox workaround: If #-Anchor detected in URL, focus this element manually w/timeout
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#") != -1) {
        var elementID = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(elementID).focus();
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

then the Focus starts working, but the **Anchor scroll** **breaks** i.e. the page isn't scrolled correctly to the anchor, it gets stuck a little high.

How do I get **both** Anchor and Focus to work inside the Document Ready for FF?

Comment: Did you try with a higher delay on the setTimeout? Something like 500...

Comment: Yes 500 worked. 100 still didn't. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.focus()` seems to be breaking the hash scroll to, which needs time to acheive.

A longer delay, but short enought for the user not noticing it, will do.

---

By the way, you could use:

```
if (window.location.hash != "") {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window.location.hash).focus();
    }, 500);
}
```

Instead of:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("#") != -1) {
    var elementID = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(elementID).focus();
    }, 10);
}
```

But that is more about code "cosmetic"...
;)